# iOS Firebase Events Don't Show in BigQuery but do in Google Analytics and Firebase Console

Tags: ios, firebase, google-analytics, google-bigquery

I'm having an issue with Firebase Events from my iOS app in that they are missing from BigQuery (Events Table) but show up in the Firebase Console and Google Analytics dashboard. Android does not have this issue for a custom event of a similar name. The event we are looking for is "ar_video_launch_ios" but the issue is the same for all iOS events.

Firebase - Shows iOS events:
[image]

Google Analytics - Shows iOS events:
[image]

BigQuery iOS - Missing iOS events:
[image]

BigQuery Android - Android event of similar name exists:
[image]

Running "Firebase/Analytics" Cocoapod v7.8.0.

The query I'm using is:

```
SELECT * FROM `<event_table_name>` where event_name like '%_ios%' LIMIT 1000
```

The same query is used to successfully pull the android events using '%_android%' so the data seems to be missing from the events table entirely. Any ideas?

Comment: @JMGelilio No, I'm not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because the app export for iOS apps is not enabled in the BigQuery firebase integration.

Follow these steps to troubleshoot:

1. Sign in to Firebase.
2. Click the Settings icon, then select Project Settings.
3. On the Project Settings page, click the Integrations tab.
4. On the BigQuery card, click View Link.
5. Now check in Google Analytics within Exported integrations
6. In exporting_apps, Select all Apps including your iOS apps

You can directly access BigQuery integration page with this link https://console.firebase.google.com/project/YourProjectNameHere/settings/integrations/bigquery

ps: You need Owner access to perform these steps.

Comment: Just had this same issue 14 months later - life saver, was very confused by why we only had Android events - must of setup the link before adding the ios app record!